# How to make double drop shadow in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, shadows, drop-shadow

I want to make something like this [artwork](https://www.behance.net/gallery/69899305/Apple-Typographic-Image).

[image]

I tried using gradient, but it look so ugly and flat. How to achieve such shadow in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: mosaic]

- Create a square: fill gray, stroke dark gray 1 pt (at the left of the image)
- From the **Appearance Panel** → add a second stroke over the fill: gradient, 8pt, Opacity: 100%, multiply.

[image: Square]

- **Appearance Panel** → click this stroke and go to **menu Effect** → **Distort & Transform** → **Transform**: move it vertically the same distance as the stroke weight

[image: transform]

- At the stroke → **Menu Effect** → **Stylize** → **Feather**

[image: feather]

- Duplicate this stroke dragging it to the **Duplicate Selected Item** icon at the Appearance panel bottom.
- Change the new stroke options: 20pt, Opacity: Multiply 35% and change the stroke color if necessary.
- Double click the Transform options and move it Vertical=0 and horizontal= the same distance as the stroke weight  but negative

[image: duplicate]

- From the **Graphic Style Panel** → create a **New Graphic Style** to keep this graphic options
- Copy the square and paste in front <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win
- Select both squares and create a Clipping Mask <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> Win

[image: Mask]

- Deselect all, click twice the **Transform Tool** and uncheck Scale Strokes and Effects to prevent the strokes from expanding when modifying the base square

[image: Strokes]

Create the mosaic with squares, rectangles or other shapes applying the Graphic Style and masking them after.

Comment: Thats very neat making 3 strokes. I thought I need to group 3 squares together to make double drop shadow. I might need to increase the feather a bit higher to make it more smooth, I think.

Comment: Of course, this is a base technique, then you must adapt everything to your own work